# Cast ascx within App_Code class

Tags: asp.net, casting, ascx, app-code

I have an ascx which I want to load and cast from a class sitting within App_Code.  I can't get it to work from the App_Code class, although I can get it to work from an aspx page.

The ASPX page technique works fine with the following code:

```
pc = LoadControl("enquirycapture.ascx");
((ASP.enquirycapture_ascx)pc).CustomProperty = customObject;
```

(Note: I have the following in the aspx page:)

```
<%@ Reference VirtualPath="~/enquirycapture.ascx" %>
```

However, when I try casting the control from within the App_Code class then it can't 'see' the ascx class, and therefore I am unable to cast to it to set the custom properties(I can load it, but not cast it).  I don't know how to replicate the <% Reference...> thing from within the App_Code class.  Anyone know how I can reference (and thus cast) my ascx from the App_Code class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`App_Code` compiles to a seperate assembly that can't reference types in a CodeFile.

But you can add interface/base class to your `App_Code` folder that identifies the custom properties and methods that you intend to implement in your usercontrol:

```
public class EnquiryCaptureBase : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public object CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and then

```
public partial class EnquiryCapture : EnquiryCaptureBase
{

}
```

and finally somewhere in `App_Code`:

```
pc = LoadControl("enquirycapture.ascx");
((EnquiryCaptureBase)pc).CustomProperty = customObject;
```

Comment: Great, just the job.  Thanks very much.